# Are "ns", "nc" and "lv" consonant clusters?

Tags: consonant-clusters

I've recently come across a number of one-syllable words with two consonants in a row + a silent E.

Here they are, grouped by the two consonants:

- NS: sense, tense, rinse, dense, expense, recompense
- NC: once, since, fence, dance, dunce, lance, ounce
- LV: valve twelve, valve, delve, solve, shelve, evolve, elves

Unlike the traditional consonant clusters I'm used to, these appear to be clusters of two graphemes:

- N + SE (where the E is silent)
- N + CE (where the E is silent)
- L + VE (where the E is silent)

Are "ns", "nc" and "lv" in fact considered consonant clusters?

If so, are there other consonant clusters like this that are followed by a Silent E?

Comment: Have you confused spelling and pronunciation here? Consonant clusters have nothing to do with spelling, which means there's no such thing as "silent e".

Comment: @tchrist yes I agree with your statement... but I haven't seen any of these examples on any lists of consonant clusters.  Just looking for confirmation that they are indeed consonant clusters!

Comment: I think this partly reflects on how English is taught as a second language, where there isn't a clear division between spelling and phonology. In linguistics, multiple consonants with no vowel between them form a [consonant cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_cluster), but as a native speaker, I wouldn't like to speculate what ESL teachers are saying. I also don't think you get many complete lists of consonant clusters in ESL, and are more likely to get examples (particularly of initial clusters) because giving every possibility would take far too long.

Comment: It reflects how English is taught, period. Native English speakers educated in Anglophone schools in Anglophone countries are generally taught that letters are the source of speech sounds, which are not mentioned again except to criticize pronunciation. Consequently native speakers are just as ignorant as adult learners when it comes to English phonology. Half the questions on ELU derive from that initial error; some are even taught that punctuation is a grammatical matter.

Comment: @StuartF They also have to occur in the same syllable to count as a cluster. So there's no tautosyllabic /ks/ cluster in words like *axis* because there's a syllable break between the /k/ and the /s/. Contrast with words like *spy* and *apse* which each have an /sp/ cluster, with the one in *spy* occurring in the syllable onset and the one in *apse* occurring in its coda. Some ESL learners cannot initially pronounce an /sp/ cluster in the onset even if they can do so in the coda because that would violate their native tongue’s phonotactics. So Spanish and Portuguese learners may say [ɛsˈpɑi̯].

Comment: Just found [a paper by John Algeo on this precise topic](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1978.11435661). Of course, it doesn't refer to spellings, but to phonology.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you so much, that paper is fantastic and I appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, "ns," "nc," and "lv" in orthography often correspond to consonant clusters in pronunciation, but not always.

Based on your question, it appears that you're interpreting "consonant cluster" to mean a sequence of consonant **letters**. A consonant cluster is actually a sequence of consonant **sounds**. As commenters have pointed out, spelling (letters) in English often doesn't map neatly to pronunciation (sounds). To look at consonant clusters in English, we have to use a system that accurately represents the sounds of the language, such as IPA (enclosed in slashes below).

The letter sequence NS can represent the consonant cluster /ns/ as in "sense" /sɛns/, but it can also represent the consonant cluster /nz/ as in "lens" /lɛnz/.

The letter sequence NC can represent the consonant cluster /ns/ as in "once" /wʌns/, but it can also represent the consonant cluster /ŋk/ as in "zinc" /zɪŋk/.

The letter sequence LV can represent the consonant cluster /lv/ as in "valve" /vælv/, but it can also correspond to the singleton (single consonant sound) /v/ as in "halve" /hæv/ or "calve" /kæv/.

As for your question about "silent E," that's a vowel **letter** corresponding to no sound, as you can see in the IPA examples above. The L in "halve" and "calve" is similarly silent.

To recap, what you call consonant clusters in your question are actually **sequences of consonant letters**, and these often correspond to consonant clusters, but sometimes they don't.

Comment: Notice how there are no consonant clusters in *pencil, uncertain, unquiet,  unconscious, insane, ensign, calvary, velvet, silver, Sylvester, insolvent, Pennsylvania* because consecutive  consonant sounds fall on different sides of a syllable boundary in each case.